# Get data from external database and display it in list view (refreshes data automatically)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Get data from external database and display it in list view.
if anyone can provide code for me I will appreciate.
(The data displayed in form of list view from the external database should refresh automatically and display any data manipulated in real time)

Comment: what do you mean by external database?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Room` to store your data. The data can then be 'observed' using `LiveData` to automatically update the `ListView`.

Here's a [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#1) that has a step by step guide for doing the above.